# How to detect if $_POST is set?

Tags: php, post

I want to know how to detect if $_POST is set or not.

Right now I detect it like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['value']))
```

But I'm not looking if value is set anymore. Basically, any POST will work.

```
if(isset($_POST))
```

I'm not sure how PHP handle this. Perhabs isset($_POST) is always returns true since it's a PHP global?

Basically, how can I do this?

Comment: `$_POST` always accompanies a header request, and **will** contain values. Maybe you want `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'`.

Comment: Do you want to figure out whether `$_POST` contains *any* data or whether the request used the HTTP POST method?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Try with:

```
if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ) {}
```

to check if your script was POSTed.

If additional data was passed, `$_POST` will not be empty, otherwise it will.

You can use `empty` method to check if it contains data.

```
if ( !empty($_POST) ) {}
```

Comment: Since `$_POST` always exists `if ($_POST)` will do just fine, no need for `empty`.

Comment: Note that `if ( !empty($_POST) ) {}` may not work if the data is sent not in key-value pairs. You might need to see `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` in that case

Comment: @DipeshParmar Describe your case.

Comment: So which one I should use for a good practise? Empty or server request method?

Comment: Server request method will give you a definitive answer on how the page was accessed. Empty or otherwise just lets you know if the variable has a value in it or not.

Comment: @LisaMiskovsky if you want to check if script was posted, use `REQUEST_METHOD` - it's good practise. If you additionaly want to check if any data was posted, check `$_POST` variable.

Comment: @LisaMiskovsky if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ) {} is the best

Comment: Okay. I already check $_POST variable for sanitization and controlling purposes. I'll go with request method. Selecting this as the answer in few minutes. Thank you.

Comment: @DipeshParmar; Thank you too, mate. Your reply was also helpful to me.

Answer (score 13):

`$_POST` is an array. You can check:

```
count($_POST)
```

If it is greater than zero that means some values were posted.

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution may well be to just use

```
if (!empty($_POST))
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use it as below. because its `super global` so its always return true when checking for `isset` and `empty`.

```
<?php
    if($_POST)
    {
        echo "yes";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Indeed, this works just fine. So should `!empty`, but it's superfluous.

Answer (score 2):

I know this answer has already been answered, but here's a simple method I'm using in one of my classes to figure whether the post has been set (perhaps someone will find it useful):

```
public function isPost($key = null) {

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST') {

        return false;

    }

    if (!empty($key)) {

        return isset($_POST[$key]);

    }

    return true;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Best way to check $_POST

```
<?php 
if(count($_POST)){}
```

Comment: Be careful with `empty()`! A string with a zero (`'0'`) is considered empty. Furthermore, it's redundant to use it together with `isset()`.