# How to refresh a page only ONCE after form submit in php?

Tags: php, forms, page-refresh

I am trying to refresh a PHP page on form submit only once. My issue is that I have multiple form elements on this page each updating something or the other. So I click on one of the form submit and I want to refresh the page only once, but using the code below:

```
echo '<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0;' . $page . '">';
```

the page keeps on reloading itself again and again. Is there a way I can get out of this loop without affecting other form elements?

Comment: Why do you need to refresh? The form submission should re-process the page..

Comment: it's not, thats the problem

Comment: can you post your form here ? and why do you want to reload ? are you loading fields like states after selecting country ?

Comment: @Mickey : yes, I am

Comment: Then don't submit form in that way, I recommend you to use AJAX for those calls. 'meta http-equiv="Refresh"' is not a way at all. It will load page in a time interval irrespective of your inputs. Instead, you can use 'onChange' in your select

Answer (score 0):

You can submit your forms with the POST method. Then detect the POST request, and meta refresh with GET method (which is the default).

Detect the POST like this:

```
if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ) {}
```

See these questions:

[Detecting request type in PHP (GET, POST, PUT or DELETE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359047/detecting-request-type-in-php-get-post-put-or-delete)

[How to detect if $_POST is set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15220704/how-to-detect-if-post-is-set)

Look into RESTful architecture on when to use POST vs. GET:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer