# Iterate filtered keys from array for use in queries

Tags: php, arrays, post, filter, key

My `$_POST` array is like this:

```
array(4){
  [4]=> string(0) ""
  [1]=> string(1) "5"
  [2]=> string(1) "3"
  [3]=> string(0) "" 
}
```

The array keys stand for the `ID` of the database entry. So I want to try to use the keys for ids to update my database.

```
for($db=0; $db<count($_POST); $db++){
    if($_POST[$db] != NULL){
        $id = key(current($_POST[$db])); //<-- Problem 
        $value = $_POST[$db];
        // query code
    }
}
```

The line with `$id` doesn't work. Can someone help me?

Comment: why dont you just use foreach ($_POST as $id => $value) ?

Comment: `foreach($_POST as $id=>$value)` ?

Comment: Thank you all for comments and Answers. It works now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than running a conditional check on every iteration of the `$_POST` array, better practice would be to filter `$_POST` before looping, then you can use your [prepared statement query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) (for security reasons) on every iteration without any conditional expressions.

It seems from your sample input that you are expecting either empty values or numeric values. Also, it is very common for database table structures to use auto-incremented `id`'s that start from `1`.  I'll provide 3 different methods, so that you can choose the most effective one for your project.  All methods preserve the original key (`id`) in `$_POST` after filtering.

Method #1: (remove all *null*, *empty*, *false-y*, *zero-ish* elements from `$_POST`)

```
foreach(array_filter($_POST) as $id=>$value){
    // insert your prepared statement query code block here
}
```

Method #2: (only permit elements from `$_POST` with a value greater than zero)

```
foreach(array_filter($_POST,function($v){return $v>0;}) as $id=>$value){
    // insert your prepared statement query code block here
}
```

Method #3: (only permit elements from `$_POST` with a value that is an integer)

```
foreach(array_filter($_POST,function($v){return is_int($v);}) as $id=>$value){
    // insert your prepared statement query code block here
}
```

> Here is a [demonstration](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f28ad1efe6993548257655c58690221f398f38b4) of all three methods.

Furthermore, there are some unnecessary checks in Sahil's answer.

First, checking `if(is_array($_POST))` will always give a `true` result because [$_POST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) is a [superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) array.  If you don't believe me, you can trust deceze's comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15220719/2943403) as he's got one of those fancy diamonds after his username.  The exception being if you are using `Content-Type:text/xml`, but surely that is not the case this time.

Second, checking the `count()` on `$_POST` is unnecessary as the `foreach()` loop will not even iterate once if the array is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Here we are iterating over this `$_POST` using `foreach`, hope this will help you out.

**Change this to:**

```
for($db=0; $db<count($_POST); $db++){
    if($_POST[$db] != NULL){
    $id = key(current($_POST[$db])); <-- Problem 
    $value = $_POST[$db]));

    --- here follows the query   ---
    }
```

**This:**

```
<?php
if(is_array($_POST) && count($_POST)>0)
{
    foreach($_POST as $id=> $value)
    {
    //$id is your id
    //$value is the value on that id    
    //--- here follows the query   ---
    }
}
```

Comment: @FabrizioCocco Thanks for accepting my post... welcome... :)

Answer (score 1):

why dont you use `foreach()`

```
foreach($db as $key => $value){
       $key is the id you need
}
```